# Get the closest point on an SDF

Tags: collision-detection, collision-resolution, signed-distance-field, raymarching

Is there a cheap and effective way to get the closest point on an SDF? (signed distance field). CodeParade made a video on a game he developed that uses SDF collisions with a sphere, how did he do it? I understand how he was able to detect if a collision occurred, but not how he got the point of collision.

Comment: This is just [gradient descent](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent), no?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the video in question: [Marble Marcher - A Fractal Physics Game](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9U0XVdvQwAI).

We can find the source code in the description: [MarbleMarcher source code](https://github.com/HackerPoet/MarbleMarcher).

Looking around in main, I see [here](https://github.com/HackerPoet/MarbleMarcher/blob/master/src/Main.cpp#L479) there is an `UpdateMarble` method of the Scene class [here](https://github.com/HackerPoet/MarbleMarcher/blob/master/src/Scene.cpp#L275). Which in turn calls [`MarbleCollision`](https://github.com/HackerPoet/MarbleMarcher/blob/master/src/Scene.cpp#L787).

There we see it uses two relevant methods:

- [`DE`](https://github.com/HackerPoet/MarbleMarcher/blob/master/src/Scene.cpp#L659): distance estimator.
- [`NP`](https://github.com/HackerPoet/MarbleMarcher/blob/master/src/Scene.cpp#L700): Nearest point.

But it does ray marching, right? I expected there would be some code that uses `DE` for ray marching, but there isn't. So looked for where does ray marching happen, and - I should have expected this - it happens in the GPU. Futhermore, the `DE` code has a counterpart in a shader [here](https://github.com/HackerPoet/MarbleMarcher/blob/master/assets/frag.glsl). But `NP` does not!

Thus, the game is not getting the nearest point from a signed distance field. It is using an alternative field that gives the nearest point (a 3D Vector) instead of the distance (a float value).

*The details of this alternative field are specific of the fractal, in a similar fashion that you have dedicated functions for the signed distance field of different shapes.*

Comment: where can I learn about these collision fields?

Comment: @CreeperCloud No idea. I want to point out that the distance estimator is not exactly a signed distance field. On a similar fashion there is something that is similar to the nearest point: support points. Perhaps learn that. See: [GJK Algorithm Explanation & Implementation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MDusDn8oTSE). - Constructing the nearest point field for simple shapes does not seem hard anyway. It might be worth exploring.